# Cassandra Java driver reports "Some contact points don't match local data center"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I had 3 node on-prem cassandra cluster with 1 node on each DC, Total 3 Data centers.(DC1,DC2,DC3)

Now I'm migrating from On-prem to GCP, So I have created another 3 DC's (DC4,DC5,DC6) on GCP and replicated the data from on-prem, After that i have made on-prem node's down(DC1,DC2,DC3) and cluster suppose to run with GCP nodes only present on (DC4,DC5,DC6).

I'm facing below error.

```
2022-08-11 14:33:24.199  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.d.d.c.NettyUtil                        : Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
2022-08-11 14:33:25.178  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.d.d.c.p.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy        : Using data-center name 'DC3' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
2022-08-11 14:33:25.179  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.d.d.c.p.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy        : Some contact points don't match local data center. Local DC = DC3. Non-conforming contact points: /1.2.3.4:9042 (DC1),/1.2.3.7:9042 (DC4),/1.2.3.9:9042 (DC6),/1.2.3.5:9042 (DC2),/1.2.3.8:9042 (DC5)
```

I have given only DC4,DC5,DC6 node ip's as contact points for Application.

my cassandra driver connection code:

```
public class CassandraCluster {

    private static final int USED_HOSTS_PER_REMOTE_DC = 2;

    final QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions();
    queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
        .setSerialConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.SERIAL);

    final DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy dCAwareRoundRobinPolicy = DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder()
        .withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc(CassandraCluster.USED_HOSTS_PER_REMOTE_DC)
        .allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel().build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate which Java driver you're using so based on the API in your sample code, I will assume that your application is using the older v3.11.

Just a minor correction, this log message is a warning (`WARN`) and not an error:

```
WARN 1 --- [           main] c.d.d.c.p.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy        : \
  Some contact points don't match local data center. Local DC = DC3. \
  Non-conforming contact points: \
    /1.2.3.4:9042 (DC1),\
    /1.2.3.7:9042 (DC4),\
    /1.2.3.9:9042 (DC6),\
    /1.2.3.5:9042 (DC2),\
    /1.2.3.8:9042 (DC5)
```

The driver reports the warning because the contact points belong to different data centres. This is normal based on your cluster topology and you should not be concerned.

What is more important is that you explicitly specify the local DC by calling `withLocalDc()`, for example:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .addContactPoint(contactpoints)
    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(
        DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder()
            .withLocalDc("DC3")
            .build()
    ).build();
```

Since you didn't specify the local DC, the driver used the first contact point's DC as the local DC. This can be dangerous in your case because if the first few contact points are unavailable, the driver can pick any DC to be "local".

For more info, see [Load balancing in Java driver v3.11](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.11/manual/load_balancing/). Cheers!